# Merging PDF files using Python and PyPDF2 throws a TypeError

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am using `Python 3.6.5` to merge PDFs together but am running into a problem.  The code below throws a `'TypeError: 'NumberObject' object is not subscriptable'` error.  What am I doing wrong?  When I comment out the line with the `merger.append`, it prints out the file paths correctly.

```
import webbrowser
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader

path = 'C:/test/pdfs'
merger = PdfFileMerger()
for pdf in os.listdir(path):
      merger.append(PdfFileReader(open(os.path.join(path,pdf), 'rb')))
      print(os.path.join(path,pdf))
merger.write(path+'/merged.pdf')
merger.close()
webbrowser.open_new(path+'/merged.pdf')
```

> File "C:\test\pdftest.py", line 9, in 
>       merger.append(PdfFileReader(open(os.path.join(path,pdf), 'rb')))
>     File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pypdf2-1.26.0-py3.6.egg\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1084, in **init**
>       self.read(stream)
>     File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pypdf2-1.26.0-py3.6.egg\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1805, in read
>       assert xrefstream["/Type"] == "/XRef"
>   TypeError: 'NumberObject' object is not subscriptable

When I change the merger.append to take a file path, I get:

> File "C:\test\pdftest.py", line 9, in 
>       merger.append(os.path.join(path,pdf))
>     File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pypdf2-1.26.0-py3.6.egg\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 203, in append
>       self.merge(len(self.pages), fileobj, bookmark, pages, import_bookmarks)
>     File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pypdf2-1.26.0-py3.6.egg\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 133, in merge
>       pdfr = PdfFileReader(fileobj, strict=self.strict)
>     File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pypdf2-1.26.0-py3.6.egg\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1084, in **init**
>       self.read(stream)
>     File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pypdf2-1.26.0-py3.6.egg\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1805, in read
>       assert xrefstream["/Type"] == "/XRef"
>   TypeError: 'NumberObject' object is not subscriptable

UPDATE:  It looks like one of the PDFs in the folder was causing this.  The only thing different with that PDF is that it uses Type 1 font whereas the other PDFs use TrueType font.  Does anyone know a workaround or fix for this?

Comment: Please post the entire traceback of the exception.

Comment: File "C:\test\pdftest.py", line 9, in <module>
    merger.append(PdfFileReader(open(os.path.join(path,pdf), 'rb')))
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pypdf2-1.26.0-py3.6.egg\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1084, in __init__
    self.read(stream)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pypdf2-1.26.0-py3.6.egg\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1805, in read
    assert xrefstream["/Type"] == "/XRef"
TypeError: 'NumberObject' object is not subscriptable

Comment: [The documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileMerger.html) says that PdfFileMerger.append takes a file object or a pathname, not a PdfFileReader.

Comment: Some of the files in `path` are not files and are not PDF files. You need to filter those out from the result of `os.listdir(path)`.

Comment: @DanD.  I've updated the post to show the traceback when I change PdfFileMerger.append to take a pathname.  Also, the files in path are all PDF files.  I created a new folder and placed the PDFs in there manually.

Comment: @DanD. I tried moving PDFs into the folder one by one and running the script and it is one of the PDFs that cause this error.  I wonder why a particular PDF file is causing this error.  I see that the only difference in properties of the PDF file is that the one that causes the error uses a Type 1 font, whereas the others use a TrueType font.  Can this be the cause?

Comment: I tried using a couple of pdfs that I had, it worked for me. I used the same code. If you want I can try using the pdfs that you have.

Comment: @AfsanAbdulaliGujarati Thank you for helping, but the PDFs I am using are private.  Thank you though!

Comment: I found that there was garbage before the header on the top of the PDF file, looked like Javascript, removed that and it started working.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be caused by either unrecognised or bad PDF formatting. I'm no PDF expert but it seems PyPDF2 is complaining about a record in the XRef table. I've found the easiest way to get around this is to reformat the PDF.

What I do is put the `merger.append(PDFFileReader(file))` in a `try` and if I find the `'NumberObject' object is not subscriptable` message in the exception I "convert" the PDF with LibreOffice in headless mode via subprocess:

```
command = [r'"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.bin"',
           '--convert-to', 'pdf', '--outdir', f'"{dest_file_path}"', f'"{file_name}"']
pdf_convert = subprocess.Popen(' '.join(command))
```

A note on using LibreOffice and subprocess: For whatever reason, I've found passing as a list causes an access denied error for me in Windows so that's why I do the `join` instead.