# While opening PDF File using PDFFileReader of PyPDF2 is throwing Error

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am using this code to open the file to find the size and dimension of PDF.

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
with open(SourceFilePath, 'rb') as f:
      input1 = PdfFileReader(f)
```

Most of the time I am able to open the PDF file using `PdfFileReader` from `PyPDF2` works fine, but with few PDF it throws this error:

```
NumberObject object is not subscriptable
```

Can anyone please help me why it is happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: When does the exception happen? Can you provide the complete stack trace, please?

Comment: Hi Pythocrates, Thanks for the response. Below is the stack trace -                                                                     '''input1 = PdfFileReader(f)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1084, in __init__
    self.read(stream)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1805, in read
    assert xrefstream["/Type"] == "/XRef"
TypeError: 'NumberObject' object is not subscriptable'''

Comment: Is it now a `NoneType object` or a `NumberObject`?

Comment: It is NumberObject only, Sorry for the mistake. Updated the question.

Comment: It sound like some broken/non-standard PDF. Maybe you can rewrite the PDF, for example using LibreOffice (or some PDF tool) as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701323/merging-pdf-files-using-python-and-pypdf2-throws-a-typeerror

Comment: Ok , thanks. Will try same.